# Execution plan shows index seek for 'is null' query on non-clustered index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

As I know index on column with null values will not help in 'is null' queries as null matches everything. So I was expecting to see Index Scan or Full table scan in execution plan.

However when I look at actual execution plan of a query I see that it's doing Index Seek.

How is this possible? Or is it a red-herring?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Null matches everything" - but I'm not aware of a reason that seeking on null wouldn't work.. I could be wrong - where did you get this information?

Comment: Its a fair question why downvoted

Comment: Well, probably because it states special expected behaviour in a special case without stating a reason that the behaviour is expected. I voted to close as unclear, because without more information, the answer appears to be "you are misinformed about what to expect".

Comment: @Blorgbeard, you seem to be an expert in sql and english, I am neither. It's better to answers someone's question than to nitpick on question itself, can you answer 1. Does sql server index null values? 2. If your answer is no, then can you explain how my query ends up in index seek?

Comment: @Ranjan you can see my ANSWER BELOW

Answer (score 0):

**As i understand your question, You are worried why query optimizer chosses index seek when all rows  has only  NUll in data it should have Index Scan or Full table Scan  because it end up reading all rows no my nullable column.
How is this possible? Or is it a red-herring?**

FIRST , 
Look at the defination of NONCLUSTERD INDEX SEEK ON TOOLTIP  "

> SCAN A PERTICULAR RANGE OF ROWS ON NONCLUSTERED INDEX

"

Seek is not always a seek through the b-tree structure sometime its a seekrange
so actually you can say there are two type of seek in sql server

> (1) Singleton Lookups :       Only when it go through B-tree direct
>   root to leaf for exact matching row, and that happen only in unique
>   index with euality predicate.
>
> (2) SEEK PLUS Range Scans  :  When it go through B-tree  root to leaf
>   then  then performs a range scan through another leaf in one direction
>   until it qulify  matching rows.

so in your case its actually a SEEK PLUS Range Scans where all rows in index qulify the data.

**SO why it did not do full table scan?**

Because you are using predicate  "SomeIO is null"
someid had Non-Unique NONCLUSTERED INDEX
and that INDEX  page size is smaller that  table/custered INDEX`s page size so its always better to read less pages that more.

SO why it did not do full INDEX SCAN why choses INDEX SEEK?

for that i'll' demostrate you execution plan with both seek and scan for same query

[image]

[image]

As you might know Sql server create multiple physical plan of logical expressed query,
and chooses query plan which has  lowest overall cost.
so you can see in above image query plan with index seek has lowest overall cost than index scan ( *one of the reason is of lower cost in above plan is estimated row size*) .
and on real world you can compare both.

PAGE read and scan count are **same** for both on my system for my TestTable

Scan count 1, logical reads 3179,

> WARM CHACHE RESULTS:

Base line is for 5 execution without paralllism

```
  ITERATOR      max time   min time    avg time
 INDEX SEEK     122 ms.    112 ms.     116 ms
 INDEX SCAN     149 ms     139 ms      145 Ms
```

ON my system Seek is winning as well.

Now that is completetly diffrent question that is this index of worthy or not.

> AFTER OP COMMENT . Does sql server index null values?

**YES IT DOES...**